# Django - Foreign Keys in Fixtures

Tags: django, fixture

I have a fixture of "User" objects (just the default Django auth ones), and am trying to create a fixture of "Profile" objects.  Each profile has a one-to-one relation to a user object, and defines some more custom stuff for that user.

As far as I can tell, the normal way of dealing with foreign keys in a fixture is to just hardcode the primary key of the foreign object into the fixture.  Is there a way to avoid doing that?

Basically, I'm trying to have something like '"user":username' in the fixture rather than '"user":pk'.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: When you say "fixture" are you referring to the json/yaml format fixtures that the django TestCase is looking for and that can also be loaded with django manage loaddata?

Answer (score 12):

What you are trying to do is serializing with natural keys, explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys).

You basically need to define *how* to *get* the object from other fields in these special manager and model methods.

Just realized that this question has been asked 9 years ago, what? Why did it appear in the feed at the **top**?

Comment: Hey it helped me so thanks for replying even after 9 years! =)