# Django: Refer to User objects in fixture for another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, fixtures

To avoid [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I will describe my problem and my attempted solution separately.

#### My problem

I have an `Appointment` model which I want to write [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures) for. There is a one-to-many mapping from the Django [`User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) to the `Appointment` model (every appointment has only one client, but a client can have multiple appointments).

I know I can hard code the primary key for the `User`s in my appointment fixtures, but would be a brittle solution. Hard coding the foreign keys also compromises the readability of my fixtures.

#### My attempted solution

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897211/django-foreign-keys-in-fixtures), which has an answer linking to [Django documentation for natural keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). However, I ran into a problem attempting to use this approach.

I believed I could create a proxy model for the `User` model, so I could create a custom [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/) for natural keys. Here is my proxy model:

```py
class UserProxy(User):
    objects = UserManager  # The UserManager class's code is omitted
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        unique_together = [['username']]
```

(If the `UserManager` class's code is relevant, please let me know in a comment, and I will add it.)

However, when I run `manage.py makemigrations`, I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
accounts.UserProxy: (models.E016) 'unique_together' refers to field 'username' which is not local to model 'UserProxy'.
    HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

I understand this error message: the `username` field belongs to the `User` model, not to the `UserProxy` model.

#### My questions

1. Is my proxy model approach a good approach? If it is not, what should I do instead?
2. If my proxy model approach is a good approach, how can I correctly refer to the `User` model's `username` field in my `unique_together` list?